# React Typescript facing issue with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component
`app.tsx`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const TestCom = () => {
 return(
     <>
     <div className="head">hey there</div>
     <select name="xyz" id="uni">
         <option value="abc">abc</option>
     </select>
     </>
 )
}

export default TestCom
```

I am testing it with jest and enzyme
`app.test.tsx`

```
import  TestCom  from "./foo";
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from "react";


 test("basic test", () => {
 const app= shallow(<TestCom />)
  expect(app.find('div.head')).to.have.lengthOf(1);
 });
```

whenever I am using .to its throwing error

```
Property 'to' does not exist on type 'JestMatchersShape<Matchers<void, ShallowWrapper<HTMLAttributes,
 any, Component<{}, {}, any>>>, Matchers<Promise<void>, ShallowWrapper<HTMLAttributes, any, 
Component<...>>>>'.ts(2339)
```

***I have tried troubleshooting but I am not able to find a fix for it***

Answer (score 2):

Until you add [chai library](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/), there is no `.to.` method. Jest [own matchers](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect) have `.toHaveLength()` that you can use:

```
expect(app.find('div.head')).toHaveLength(1);
```